# How to evaluate the hypothesis that a set of samples belongs to the common general population if only the mean & stadard deviation are available?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have *n* results of [**nested sampling** analyses from prior distribution MCMC](https://github.com/BEAST2-Dev/nested-sampling). Every one  has its own estimation of marginal likelihood & its standard deviation.

The analysis has a hyperparameter – *subchain length*. It defines a minimum number of links that separates two states of interest, & is necessary to enforce *the independence* of sampled points. It is stated that **chain length** of usual MCMC run divided by **effective sample size** (**ESS**) is sufficient criterion but the number turns out too large. Usually substantially less numbers are used but this demands the control of consistency. It is written in [FAQ](https://github.com/BEAST2-Dev/nested-sampling/wiki/FAQ) for two runs that if the marginal likelihood estimations difference is less than two deviations of the estimations sum, the *subchain length* is acceptable.

The problem is how to repeat the same with larger number of runs? Thereby, there are a number of samples of marginal likelihood estimations for which I do not have individuals but only standard deviations. How to evaluate that they belong to the one common general population?

This sounds as the work for Student's t-test, but it is based on the assumption that samples are normal. I have no guess about the form of marginal likelihoods estimations distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed further here (probably you opened the issue): https://github.com/BEAST2-Dev/nested-sampling/issues/14

Usually nested sampling is very sensitive to the evidence Z, so if you vary the hyperparameter and find different ln(Z) values, you may want to tune the hyperparameter to be more conservative until ln(Z) is stable. For more information, see
https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09675 .